# CSS Placeholder animations - How to handle "optional" state

Tags: css, sass

I'm in the process of creating some custom placeholder animations and overall they work really well! ...assuming the inputs are required, anyway.

What I'm trying to do is have my "optional" fields operate the same way. I'm utilizing the `:valid` pseudoclass to determine if the placeholder animation should activate, but the problem with optional fields is that they are always "valid". Is there any way to get around this?

Here is my CSS:

```
.form-group {
    position:relative;
}

.form-control {
    border:0;
    border-radius:0;
    padding-left:0;
    padding:15px 10px 3px 0;

    &:valid {
      &+ label {
        top:0;
        opacity:1;
      }
    }

    &+ label {
        position:absolute;
        top:4px;
        opacity:0;
        pointer-events:none;
        font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
        color:#999;
        left:0px;
        font-size:11px;
        z-index:2;
        transition:.15 ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of an optional field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Website (optional)" />
    <label>Website (optional)</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [placeholder-shown pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown), but this is an experimental technology and isn't supposed on all browsers (but you'll be okay on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari).

Comment: I appreciate you giving the heads up. I was looking at this, but we're aiming to support IE as well. Thanks though!